# Modifying individual field form inputs (CSS, Placeholder, etc) Drupal 7 registration form preprocess

Tags: forms, drupal, attributes, preprocessor, textfield

I'm attempting to preprocess CSS and placeholder etc to the form inputs for the Registration Form. I'm manually rendering each field input on the registration form.

The following code works fine for email or password, but not 'custom fields'.

```
$form['account']['mail']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Email address');
    $form['account']['mail']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'email-input';
    $form['account']['mail']['#title_display'] = "invisible";
    $form['account']['mail']['#description'] = t('');
```

When I apply the same to the custom fields, it won't apply.
I have looked through the user module and printed avialable varibles

```
$form['field_first_name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('First Name');
    $form['field_first_name']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'first-name-input';
    $form['field_first_name']['#title_display'] = "invisible";
    $form['field_first_name']['#description'] = t('');
```

I found multiple mentions of field_first_name in the variable print out, but I'm unable to modify the text inputs directly.

Comment: try changing the form values in the tpl file where you are rendering the form. it should work

Comment: Print the form array and make sure you are using correct nested array when modifying the fields.